# What is wrong with this multiple inner joins query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, recursion

I am trying to execute the SQL query below (In an Access DB) and I get a type mismatch error.

```
SELECT S1.[Main Project] AS Company, S1.[Main Link] AS Project, S1.[Name] AS Milestone, S1.[Start] As MilestoneDueDate, 
S2.[Name] As Successor1, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate1, 
S3.[Name] As Successor2, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate2, 
S4.[Name] As Successor3, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate3, 
S5.[Name] As Successor4, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate4, 
S6.[Name] As Successor5, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate5, 
S7.[Name] As Successor6, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate6, 
S8.[Name] As Successor7, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate7, 
S9.[Name] As Successor8, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate8, 
S10.[Name] As Successor9, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate9, 
S11.[Name] As Successor10, S2.[Start] as SuccessorDueDate10

FROM ((((((((((Sheet1 AS S1 
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S2 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 1] = S2.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S3 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 2] = S3.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S4 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 3] = S4.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S5 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 4] = S5.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S6 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 5] = S6.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S7 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 6] = S7.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S8 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 7] = S8.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S9 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 8] = S9.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S10 
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 9] = S10.[ID])
INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS S11
ON S1.[Outcoming Task 10] = S11.[ID])

WHERE S1.Start >S2.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S3.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S4.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S5.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S6.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S7.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S8.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S9.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S10.[Start]
OR S1.Start >S11.[Start]

ORDER BY S1.[Main Project]
```

Am I using the inner joins correctly?

I know this table is horrible (actually the guy who developed it should have created a relation ship table), but it is what is :(

Is there a more elegant way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? The actual error message would be fantastic. Information about the tables and how they're linked might also be useful.

Comment: Hi Anthony, the error message is type mismatch and there is only one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type mismatch suggests that Access is trying to compare two things that are different types.    It is probably one or more of your 20 comparison statements that is causing this. I suggest you try to reproduce this error with simple queries, such as the following:

```
select 1 from Sheet1 as S1 inner join Sheet1 as S2
   on S1.[Outcoming Task 1] = S2.[ID];
```

Test different fields in this manner until you see where the type mismatch is.

As far as a more elegant solution, that depends on what you are trying to do.  If you update your question with a description of the goal of this query, we can help with a better solution.

If you have to do any significant amount of work with this data, I recommend getting it out of the bad format as quickly as possible.  If you can get the source file restructured, great.  If not, it still might be worthwhile to make your own temporary tables that are formatted in a logical way and use them to do whatever work you need to do.